# Client not configured to receive access tokens via browser IdentityServer4

Tags: javascript, authentication, identityserver4, openid

```
let usrMgr = new UserManager({
  authority: "https://localhost:5001/",
  client_id: "clientname",
  redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000/login/callback.html",
  response_type: "id_token token",
  scope: "openid"
});

usrMgr.signinRedirect();
```

I'm using [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)
to authenticate with our identity server as shown above.

When trying to authenticate I'm getting the following error from the identity server

[image: Error]

My client on the identity server looks like this

```
{
    "Enabled": true,
    "ClientId": "clientname",
    "ClientName": "Some Client Name",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": "implicit",
    "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "email", "id:custom" ],
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "https://localhost:3000/signout-callback-oidc" ],
    "RedirectUris": [ "https://localhost:3000/login/callback.html" ],
    "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "https://localhost:3000/signout-oidc",
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true
  }
```

I have AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser set to true as well as having AllowedGrantTypes set to implicit.

Any ideas why I'm getting the "Client not configured to receive access tokens via browser error?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the IdentityServer source-code you see

```
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // check if response type contains an access token,
        // and if client is allowed to request access token via browser
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var responseTypes = responseType.FromSpaceSeparatedString();
        if (responseTypes.Contains(OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.Token))
        {
            if (!request.Client.AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser)
            {
                LogError("Client requested access token - but client is not configured to receive access tokens via browser", request);
                return Invalid(request, description: "Client not configured to receive access tokens via browser");
            }
        }
```

So, the only reason I think is if you have some typo in your config file or there are some other reason the AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser is not set to true. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs). Perhaps some upper/lower-casing issue?